# Unable to run flutter commands

Tags: flutter

When I had previously setup flutter, all was working well, however, now all of the flutter commands are resulting in this error:

> Error: Error when reading '../../../../documents/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/snapshots/pub.dart.snapshot': No such file or directory
>   Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (1 tries left)
>   Command 'pub upgrade' still failed after 10 tries, giving up.```

How do I solve this?

Comment: connect your computer to the Internet - seems it tries to upgrade your flutter installation

Comment: It is connected to the internet and I've tried it several times. Is there anything else I can try? @pskink

Comment: hmmm, If London is not in China behind the Great Firewall, then I have no idea...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like something went wrong while downloading the dart sdk. Can you delete the cache folder inside bin and then run flutter doctor again? What's the output?

Are you by any chance behind a firewall (or using a proxy) that might be blocking the download of the dart sdk?

Comment: I thought it had fixed it but the error returned when I ran ```flutter pub get```. I have also checked that I'm not using any proxies or behind a firewall that could block the sdk download. @masumbillahsanjid